# Suggestion for missing laptop wifi driver - HP 17-by1061st

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers

I installed **Kubuntu 20.04** and have noticed that WIFI does not work.  I went to the HP site and no drivers are available (not even for Windows).  The laptop came preinstalled with Windows.  Can someone provide me with some suggestions to get my **wireless card** working with Ubuntu?  Thank you!

UPDATE:

I went to the product specs and found that Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11b/g/n/ac (1x1) Wi-Fi is used.  On the Realtek site, there are only Windows drivers.  Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know what driver the laptop will need by running this command

```
 lspci | grep Network
```

it will probably give you something like

```
 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

For the installation you need either wired or UMTS/LTE internet access
Then go to [this repo](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) and download the content right side -> green button "clone or download" and get the zip-file.
Unzip the file and rename the folder from rtl8821ce-master to rtl8821ce. 
Run these commands on terminal:

```
cd Downloads/rtl8821ce/
sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms
sudo m-a prepare
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Wait until it’s done and then reboot your notebook.

In some cases you might need to disable secure boot if the driver hasn’t installed after you followed the steps above.
Click the network icon and check if there are some Wi-Fi Networks.
Have fun

Comment: Thank you so very much, your suggestion worked wonderfully.  I would just like to add that the second command above requires a wired connection since the command requests additional files off the internet.  The first time I ran the second command I realized this and plugged the laptop, re-executed the command and worked flawlessly from there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - edited and clarified my answer

Comment: I wanted to mention that this morning, I had no WIFI for some unknown reason.  It turns out that in my bios, 'secure boot' was set.  I simply disabled it and it worked again.  I must have changed this bios setting unknowingly or hit 'factory defaults' which caused this problem.